# Battery state and level thanks to the background fetch?

Tags: ios, swift, background, fetch, battery

I want to know when the user of the app plug or unplug his phone's charger even when the app is in the background. I can do that with the NetworkReachability (wifi, ondata, not-reachable, not determine...) but not with the battery level or the battery state.
I can know the battery level and the battery state only when the app is in the foreground or active unlike when she's in the background.

Can I set a background fetch for the battery level(or state)? If the user unplug his charger, I would launch a function or a print (or whatever).

Can I set listeners on the battery level or state ? Because that's how I did for the NetworkReachability but I found only observers available for the battery characteristics.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let a = window?.rootViewController as? UIViewController{
            UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.batteryStateDidChange), name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.batteryLevelDidChange), name: .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }

    else{
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }
```

And it seems like observers don't work with the background fetch or I'm conding wrong ?

I'm really thankful for your help, have a nice day everybody!

Comment: You cannot/should not use observers or timers in a background fetch operation. The operating system will give you a limited time slot to fetch some data in the background at a random time chosen by the OS. It is expected that the background operation should return in a timely manner as the time slot that you get will be limited. If it takes a long time the OS will likely kill the operation and then not give your app much (if any) time for future background fetches and if Apple detect what you are doing they will likely reject your app

Comment: Yeah, I know, so how do I put listeners for the battery level (and state) please?

Comment: You cant whilst the app is backgrounded.

Comment: But I can do that to check Network Reachability. If the user is on WiFi or on data, background fetch will tell me. Thanks to a listener ....

Comment: If i remember rightly, NetworkReachability class is not even an Apple class, it was built as part of AFNetworking / Alamofire. Its a completely different. You can get the battery state and level using the [UIDevice class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice). it has properties for battery level and state. you can also monitor for changes when not in background

Comment: Yeah exactly, so I can't monitor for changes about battery level and state when I'm in the background? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I said that 17 mins ago lol, good luck with the project

Comment: Can I ask you a question, please?

Is there a possible way to use the CoreMotion in the background to wake up my app when the user is driving or walking or whatever?
Like, if the user starts driving (with his car), I start location. (I don't want to use the GPS at first because, in a campaign, it wouldn't work properly.)
I promise it's my last comment! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer, it looks like it wasn't the case, but often these types of questions boil down to trying to defer/cancel intensive, but otherwise discretionary work. **If** that happens to be the case, I've had great luck with using the `NSProcessInfo` low power APIs. There's even a notification for when it becomes enabled, which is particularly useful for cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to check this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) on background modes available in iOS, it explains what background modes there are and what you can use them for.

Apple dont use core motion primarily for detecting when driving, it knows I am driving as soon as my phone connects to the car via bluetooth, before I even move. the short answer to both your questions is...

When your app is in the background its not really running. its in like a suspended state. When you first background it you have a short amount of time you can do stuff before it is fully backgrounded but not long. Once backgrounded you can only do things in either background fetch, controlling audio (that was started in the app already before backgrounding), GPS location updates and push notifications (I think that is all of them).

So you cannot run long running tasks in the background to monitor battery levels or use core motion to detect movement. You could use GPS and if the speed increases over what you would expect a human can reach then you could presume that they are driving.